# How to catch natgrid's griddata errors

Tags: python, matplotlib, interpolation

I'm trying to interpolate 2D data using the `griddata` function of mlab with the natgrid package installed.

However, my data is causing two types of errors:

```
Natgrid - two input triples have the same x/y coordinates
            but different data values: 

                First triple:  0.000000 45.000000 20.743004
                Second triple: 0.000000 45.000000 20.572077
```

and when I remove the duplicate points (as suggested [here](http://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Support/talk_archives/2012/3384.html)) I get:

```
natgrid - error number 1 from ReadData:
  Insufficient data in gridded region to triangulate
```

The main issue with this is that there is no way of catching the errors. And when they occur, the python process terminates abruptly.

How do I handle these `griddata` specific errors and how do I catch them and continue my script?

Comment: are those the whole error messages that you get?

Comment: yes, that is all I get as output from the natgrid error. My IDE then reports that `Process finished with exit code -1073741819` for the second error and `Process finished with exit code 1` for the first.

Comment: Can you run you code with the debugger and update your question with the backtrace. Just do this: `python -m pdb my_script.py`. When the error is return you should be left in a python console. If this is the case just type `tb` and hit `enter` and you'll have the list of function calls before the crash happened

Answer (score 0):

If `griddata` calls `sys.exit()` after printing the error message you can catch it:

```
try:
    griddata(....)
except:
    do what needs to be done
```

If the buildin `exit()` is called instead, I think that there is nothing to be done to catch the error and continue working.

If I call `sys.exit()` in Ipython, I get:

> An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
>
> SystemExit
>
> To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D

and the backtrace shows that `sys.exit()` is nothing but a `KeyboardInterrupt`.

Instead, I think that the building `exit()` just kill the python interpreter (at least on the python2.7 shipped with ubuntu)

Comment: I found the [Python interface to NCAR natgrid library](https://github.com/matplotlib/natgrid) (not sure if it is the official one). But I am not proficient in C/C++ and so I'm having a hard time figuring out where and how it is handling the errors. I will contact the named developer to see if he can help.

Comment: It looks like the official one. If NCAR is in C/C++ I doubt that it's easy to deal with the errors. If the library and the interface are well designed you might be able to get hold to an error code returned by Natgrid or to catch an exception (if C++).